# creationdate of GoPro video returns current time and date

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

```
let dateVideo = AVAsset(url: self.pickedURL!).creationDate?.value as! Date
```

This method only seems to work on videos shot on iPhone.
I want to have the creationdate for GoPro videos too. The time and date have to be available somehow since other apps are able to correctly display the creationdate.

Can somebody identify what is going on here?